# How to preserve the order of mongoID in an array after a mongo query

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting

Im trying to query an array of mongoIds and return data in the same order, however whenever I try to do this the order is not the same as declared below.

Sample code:

```
let id = [
            "620d323b8d0273004c8993a4",
            "620d32498d0273004c8993a5",
            "61e730a745171f002d85df4b",
            "620cfe708d0273004c89933a"
        ]

let test = await User.find({'_id': {$in: id}}, 'id text')
console.log(test)
```

After logging test the output returned as:

```
[
   {"_id": "61e730a745171f002d85df4b"}, 
   {"_id": "620cfe708d0273004c89933a"}, 
   {"_id": "620d323b8d0273004c8993a4"}, 
   {"_id": "620d32498d0273004c8993a5"}
]
```

I want to return this as the first code snippet, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      _id: {
        "$in": [
          "620d323b8d0273004c8993a4",
          "620d32498d0273004c8993a5",
          "61e730a745171f002d85df4b",
          "620cfe708d0273004c89933a"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "docs": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "docs": {
        "$map": {
          "input": [
            "620d323b8d0273004c8993a4",
            "620d32498d0273004c8993a5",
            "61e730a745171f002d85df4b",
            "620cfe708d0273004c89933a"
          ],
          "as": "s",
          "in": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$docs",
              "as": "d",
              "cond": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$d._id",
                  "$$s"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$docs"
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": {
      "$first": "$docs"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YP75dmYFNoF)